# How to encode for special character?

Tags: c#, text-files, special-characters

I am having an issue with my file output. I need to write to a file the character ý and þ. I can do this using Convert.ToChar(0253) & Convert.ToChar(0254). This is an old program that I have rewritten in C# from basic+. The old program created a simple text file that if opened in wordpad would render the special characters ý & þ. However, when I create the file and open it in wordpad it renders the characters as Ã½ and Ã¾. Below is the output file opened in both notepad and wordpad. How can I output the characters so that they will render as ý and þ in both notepad and wordpad? I have also inserted my code below. Thanks in advance.

This renders fine in notepad like so:

```
3/31/2015ý15þ
14182515þ
ENDþ
```

However, when opening the file in wordpad it renders like this:

```
3/31/2015Ã½15Ã¾
14182515Ã¾
ENDÃ¾


textOut.WriteLine(shortDate + Convert.ToChar(0253) + cRenPer + Convert.ToChar(0254));
```

Comment: Why don't you save as UTF8 or even UTF16?

Comment: You need to set the encoding... what is `textOut`?

Comment: The textout is a streamwritter. Here is the code piece.                StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(new FileStream((dirPath + batchNum + ".REN"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

Comment: Ok, I did the encoding as suggested and yes it works perfectly. Thanks so much for the help. How can I give you the credit Thorsten Dittmar?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : you have to change your comment to an answer to get credit from it.

Comment: @Falanwe I just did - I just didn't think that this simple thing would actually solve the problem :-D

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: the most simple answers are often the best ones

Answer (score 2):

You should specify either UTF8 or UTF16 encoding when writing the file. You can do it like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(<file path>, false, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the encoding when you define the streamreader

```
StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(new FileStream((dirPath + batchNum + ".REN"),
                                        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write),
                                        Encoding.UTF8);
```

[MSDN for this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @JoshuaOglesbee - No worries, you may also want to look into using [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate your file paths, it helps make sure that you dont have too many /'s and that they're the right way round for whatever platform you're on ;) Also, note the `Encoding.UTF8`, you don't need to recreate it :)

Answer (score 1):

So, as Thorsten Dittmar had suggested I needed to encode the stream-writer as utf8. This allowed the file to be read by the preexisting application as it should be. Below is the change to the stream-writer class.

```
 StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter((dirPath + batchNum + ".REN"), false, new UTF8Encoding(true));
```

This is an edit: I ended up modifying the code. Although the text file ended up being interpreted correctly in word-pad it was still not being read by the legacy application. My modified code is below:

```
 StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(new FileStream((dirPath + batchNum + ".REN"),
                                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write),
                                    System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default);
```

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. Generally it's not desired that you write your own answer, so I suggest you delete this answer and accept one that helped you (for example mine, as you wrote in your answer that my comment lead you to the solution of your problem :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - I don't think deletion is necessary, it is good to see that the OP came to a solution based off comments, I do agree though that it generally isn't required

Answer (score 0):

You could write to file using the following code , 
note the 2nd encoding parameter.
This will effect how the file is encoded , which in turn will effect how will ite will be treated by various text editors.

```
string fileName = "myFile.txt";
using (TextWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(fileName),System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
{
         textOut.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(0254));
}
```